# What signifies a reporting clause?

Tags: grammar, speech, quoting

I know reporting clauses are punctuated thus:

- (1) *She said, 'We are about to close you know?'*

but what if the phrase prior to the speech is not a speech tag. For example, is it:

- (2) *She looked cross, 'We are about to close you know?'*

or:

- (3) *She looked cross. 'We are about to close you know?'*

And what about:

- (4) *The shop was gloomy inside, 'We are about to close you know?'*

Comment: A bare << The shop was gloomy inside. 'We are about to close you know?' >> is infelicitous, implying that the shop has the power of rational speech. // The introductory comma is not considered the only acceptable punctuation between quotative verb and quote. Colons are sometimes suitable, but here I'd opt for zero punctuation: << She said 'We are about to close you know?' >> // There are novel quotative verbs, eg  << She smiled 'We are about to close you know?' >> // However, with **no** quotative verb, the intro needs a period as Kate says. But the speaker must be referenced. (3) yes; (4) no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words preceding a piece of direct speech are not an actual reporting clause (*He said* or its equivalent), they count as a separate sentence and need to end with a full stop (period).

Comment: He had forgotten all about the question. 'Thank you!' he said much later.